# How can I make variables alternate values within the same repeating function?

Tags: javascript, variables, calculator, var

Okay, so the answer to my question might not be the problem but here's a go anyway.

Basically this is one part of a calculator program. I need to know how I can take the `var y` on **only the first execution** of this function (assuming it will likely be executed repeatedly) and have the variable x be converted to that value and hold that value for each subsequent execution  ... while still allowing for `output.original_value` to be changed when another function is called that wants to change its value.  This is the only part of my program that I have not been able to figure out.

Essentially I am trying to emulate a common calculator function where if the user presses 1+2 and then = the calculation will render 3 and then will increase by the value of the second number (2 in this case) for each subsequent pressing of = (ie. 1+2=3 = 5 = 7....) my calculator right now is doing the opposite (ie. 1+2 = 3 = 4 = 5 = 6.........).

(I have tried many many things... for now at the end of the function I have `mathSign = null` which prevents the program from being run more than once without another function first reseting the values...  I did not leave that part in the posted code because my end goal is to not have to use it.)

```
function result(){
  var x = output.original_value;
  var y = parseFloat(output.value);

  if(mathSign == '+'){
    output.value = x + y;
  }
  else if(mathSign == '-'){
    output.value = x - y;
  }
  else if(mathSign == '*'){
    output.value = x * y;
  }
  else if(mathSign == '/'){
    output.value = x / y;
  }
  else if(mathSign == 'n^'){
    output.value = Math.pow(x,y);
  }
  else if(mathSign == 'reciprocal'){
    output.value = 1 / output.original_value;
    mathSign = null;
  }
  else if(mathSign == 'sqrt'){
    output.value = Math.sqrt(output.original_value);
    mathSign = null;
  }

  output.result = output.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the best way to solve my problem.  It is in essence a variable switcher and works amazingly with the rest of my calculator code :-)

```
function variable_toggle(){
  output.variable_toggle;
  if(output.value == mathSign){
    output.value = output.original_value;
  }
  if(output.variable_toggle != false){
    var x = output.original_value;
    var y = parseFloat(output.value);
    output.toggled_value = parseFloat(output.value);
    result(x, y);
    output.variable_toggle = false;
  }
  else{
    var x = parseFloat(output.value);
    var y = parseFloat(output.toggled_value);
    result(x, y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
  if( typeof result.first == 'undefined' ) {
        result.first = 0;
        result.y = parseFloat(output.value);
        alert (result.y);
        var y = result.y;
    }
    else 
    {
        var y = result.y;
        alert (y);
    }
```

putting that instead of var y= parseFloat(output.value), basically it's checking for some static variable first if it's set and if it's not(first pass), you set y, and every other time you just use that first y. I think it should work

Comment: Okay, well I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work. It worked for like 2 clicks then no more.  The problem is that as of right now when the function is repeatedly called in succession `var x` is stationary and unchanching while `var y` takes on the value of the optput each time.  This is okay, but I need `var x` to take the value of `y` on the first run through and then hold that value constant on each subsequent click of the `=` button.

Comment: Could you send your code, so I can try, it would be much easier that way

Comment: or you can zip it and send, posting whole thing here would be crazy

Comment: you can send the zip file, it's much easier when you can really test it

Comment: I changed the answer so you can check it out

Comment: a stroke of genius came over me and I solved the problem! :-)

Comment: thats similar to my answer but not 100% the same.`function variable_toggle(){
  output.variable_toggle;
  if(output.variable_toggle != false){
    var x = output.original_value;
    var y = parseFloat(output.value);
    output.toggled_value = parseFloat(output.value);
    result(x, y);
    output.variable_toggle = false;
  }
  else{
    var x = parseFloat(output.value);
    var y = parseFloat(output.toggled_value);
    result(x, y);
  }
}

function result(x, y){...rest of code in function...}`

Comment: and one more thing, it's better to use else if statement, because you don't need to check for every sign, if it's '+' it can't be '-' also ;)